# What is the corresponding function for mean_validation_score in grid.cv_results_?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

In older version of scikit-learn, we obtained the list of mean of cross validation scores by `[result.mean_validation_score for result in grid.grid_scores_]`. However starting from 20.0 scikit-learn, we are no longer able to use `grid.grid_scores_`. Instead, there is `grid.cv_results_`. Here is my question. Which of the following methods in `grid.cv_results_` correspond to mean_validaton_score we got from `grid.grid_scores_`?

- mean_train_score
- mean_test_score

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to GridSearchCV documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), you have to convert your `grid.cv_results_` into a Pandas DataFrame and you can then freely access both *mean_train_score* and *mean_test_score* data:

```
import pandas as pd

cv_results = pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)

print(cv_results['mean_train_score'])
print(cv_results['mean_test_score'])
```

The first one, `mean_train_score`, is the mean score you obtained from the training folds (*in-fold*), `mean_test_score` is the mean score you got from the validation folds (*out-of-fold*).

Basically, you are interested just in `mean_test_score` for a strict evaluation of the hyper-parameters' performances, but `mean_train_score` can help you figure out how much the model has fitted the data using certain parameters and how much this is relative to test data (for instance by building a validation curve plot, see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question is that which one (cv_results['mean_train_score'] or cv_results['mean_test_score']) corresponds to mean_validation_score?

Comment: I've added the answer you were looking for